# Need one animated DIV to move another

Tags: jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/pC6fC/1/

I have two divs, one above the other. When the first animates, which it does, it slides below the other. How can I make sure that when the first animates it pushes the second downwards without having to animate both DIVs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use margin, instead of top. As both of your divs are relatively positioned, if you set top value (i.e. 30%), it won't push your second div.

Example with margin-top: http://jsfiddle.net/pC6fC/5/

Answer (score 3):

You can do this either by animating the `margin-top` instead of the `top`, or another idea would be to put them both into a `parent div` and animate that one.

example1:
http://jsfiddle.net/pC6fC/8/

example2:
http://jsfiddle.net/pC6fC/6/

Comment: @powerbuoy was just adding them myself but thanks for the trouble :D

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with modifying your jQuery a little..

1. If you want the div to slide after your animation of box1 is completed.

   ```
   /* Slides down alert banner */
   $(function(){
       $(".link").click(function(){
           $(".box1").animate({top:150}, 500, function () { $(".box2").css({top:150});});

       });
   ```

   });
2. If you want the div to slide along with animation of box1.

   ```
   /* Slides down alert banner */
   $(function(){
       $(".link").click(function(){
       $(".box1").animate({top:150}, 500);
       $(".box2").css({top:150});
       });
   });
   ```